# Unable to create BitmapImage from Pictures library using UriSource

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have WindowsPhone 8.1 RT application. I want to create a simple BitmapImage and display it on the UI.

The image is saved in the `Screenshots` folder of the pictures library. When I try to create the BitmapImage using the following code, it always fails and empty area is displayed.

```
string imageLocation = "C:\\Data\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\wp_ss_20150923_0001.png"
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageLocation), UriKind.Absolute);
imageControl.Source = bitmapImage;
```

But when I read the storage file and create a stream, and set it using `SetSourceAsync`, the image is displayed.

```
StorageFile imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileAsync(imageLocation);
var stream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(bitmapImage);
imageControl.Source = bitmapImage;
```

Why can't I see the image being loaded in the image control when I use the `Uri` method to set image source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is "sandboxed", meaning it can not directly access the file system. And the Pictures library doesn't provide any URI-schema for accessing the images.

There's an [another quite similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245310/winrt-how-to-read-images-from-the-pictures-library-via-an-uri).

Here's some more information regarding [file access on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758319(v=win.10).aspx) in WinRT. You may find the ["Access media libraries"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx) especially interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

> new Image() {
>       Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/example.png")) })

Comment: I don't think that would work either for image stored in the Pictures folder. Please read the accepted answer for the reason.